# What is fs.root in html5?

Tags: html

I'm new in HTML5, trying to understand a part of HTML5. The requirement is to create a folders and files on web application.

```
 function CreateFolder() {
            if (document.querySelector('#folderName').value.length == 0) {
                alert("Please enter folder name to create!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                var path = document.getElementById("folderName").value;
                CreateDir(fs.root, path.split('/')); // fs.root is a DirectoryEntry.
                ListFoldersFiles();
                alert("Folder created !");
            }
        }
```

`fs.root`, what does it do ? where exactly the folder will get created on my computer? I'm not able to find out the folder once it says Folder Created. Some more functions are here .

```
//  CREATE DIRECTORY
    function CreateDir(rootDirEntry, folders) {
        // remove the bad folder names like
        if (folders[0] == '.' || folders[0] == '') {
            folders = folders.slice(1);
        }
        rootDirEntry.getDirectory(folders[0], { create: true }, function (dirEntry) {
            // Recursively add the new subfolders, if any
            if (folders.length) {
                CreateDir(dirEntry, folders.slice(1));
            }
        }, handleError);
    }


<ul id="folderList"></ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where is fs.root (HTML5) in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481995/where-is-fs-root-html5-in-windows)

Comment: Please rollback your title update, It is not where to put a lot of question, it is a subject header.

Comment: where it find the created folders on windows.

Comment: Follow the dupe link above and you find an answer.